# CentOS: delete line contain string in txt files

Tags: linux, centos

The title look familiar but it's different requirement.

I have 2 txt file:
 first one :

```
./aaa/bbb/ccc.txt
./hhh/fff.txt
./abc.txt
./gh/gh/jj.txt
```

second :

```
 fff
 abc
```

Expected result:

```
./aaa/bbb/ccc.txt
./gh/gh/jj.txt
```

Second file contain only file name (with out extension).
I want to remove all lines in first file with have file name in second file.

Please help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Fvf second_file first_file
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F: use literal strings instead of the default BRE
-v: print non-matching
-f file: take patterns from the given file
```

Comment: I want to share this to anyone need it